# How to build a executable for ironpython files and a .Net dll file?

Tags: .net, executable, ironpython

I have two python files (Iron Python 2.7) and a .net dll file.

- abc.py
- def.py
- ghi.dll

abc.py is the Main file that contains the code for Windows Forms application and def.py is a supporting  file that has the functions. ghi.dll is a third party api file that has been modified to dll.
I want to create this to an Windows Forms Application executable to distribute it to others in my team.
Used Visual Studio 2017 to write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a folder and copy all the required .net dlls from the **C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0** folder and copy all the required files from the **C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib** folder
- Copy the ipyc.exe from **C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7** folder and copy pyc.py from **C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Tools\Scripts** folder
- Open Command Prompt and navigate to the appropriate folder and use the following command
      **ipyc def.py /main:abc.py /target:winexe**